# Do I need to delete arangodb cursor after query?

Tags: arangodb

I want to know whether a cursor can be auto deleted or should I delete it manually. If I don't delete it, does it cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be automatically deleted when you retrieve all requested documents. From [docs](http://docs.arangodb.org/HttpAqlQueryCursor/AccessingCursors.html):

> The cursor will automatically be destroyed on the server when the
>   client has retrieved all documents from it. The client can also
>   explicitly destroy the cursor at any earlier time using an HTTP DELETE
>   request. The cursor id must be included as part of the URL.
>
> Note: the server will also destroy abandoned cursors automatically
>   after a certain server-controlled timeout to avoid resource leakage.

Comment: Thanks. How to know what's the value of the server-controlled timeout.

Comment: The default timeout currently is 30 seconds, but it may change in future versions. To specify a user-defined timeout, you can put the timeout value into the `ttl` attribute of the HTTP request sent to the REST API `POST /_api/cursor`.